# Laravel - SELECT all from table with the result from previous SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to perform the following query in Laravel but have had trouble working out the DB class and Eloquent classes. 
I would like to do something like the following..

`$week = DB::select('SELECT week FROM calendar WHERE year = 2015 and month = 01 and day = 30');
$secondResult = DB::select("SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE year = 2015 and week = $week");
return View::make('calendar')->with('weekdays',$secondResult);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
$week = DB::select('SELECT week FROM calendar WHERE year = 2015 and month = 01 and day = 30');
     foreach ($week as $weekvalue)
{
   echo  $weekname=$weekvalue->week;
}

$secondResult = DB::select("SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE year = 2015 and week = $weekname");
return View::make('calendar')->with('weekdays',$secondResult);
```